# gettext upper and lower cases

Tags: localization, gettext, poedit

In gettext, is there a way to avoid duplicating upper and lower case translations? right now my translations looks like this, which works but it is duplicating.

```
msgid "Customer Service"
msgstr "Kontakta oss"

msgid "CUSTOMER SERVICE"
msgstr "KONTAKTA OSS"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two strings are different, there’s nothing “duplicated” here.

If you don’t want such translation entries, change your code to not contain both literals and do case changes programatically.